# Angular 6 mysterious stacktrace: globalZoneAwareCallback

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular-router

last recently, using Angular6 I started to observe exceptionally poorly descriptive stacktrace in the browser console:

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>   resolvePromise
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3136:31 resolvePromise
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3093:17 scheduleResolveOrReject
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3195:17 invokeTask
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2743:17 onInvokeTask
>   http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:36899:24 invokeTask
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2742:17 runTask
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2510:28 drainMicroTaskQueue
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2917:25 invokeTask
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2822:21 invokeTask
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3862:9 globalZoneAwareCallback
>   http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3888:17 core.js:1673
>   defaultErrorLogger
>   core.js:1673
>   ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
>   /ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
>   core.js:1719
>   next
>   core.js:4319:109
>   ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
>   /EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<
>   core.js:3555:34
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js
>   /SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub
>   Subscriber.js:195
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js
>   /SafeSubscriber.prototype.next
>   Subscriber.js:133
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js
>   /Subscriber.prototype._next
>   Subscriber.js:77
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js
>   /Subscriber.prototype.next
>   Subscriber.js:54
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next
>   Subject.js:47
>   ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit
>   core.js:3539:52
>   onHandleError/<
>   core.js:3846:48
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/
>   zone.js:388
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/
>   zone.js:138
>   ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
>   /NgZone.prototype.runOutsideAngular
>   core.js:3783
>   onHandleError
>   core.js:3846
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
>   /
>   zone.js:392
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/
>   zone.js:154
>   _loop_1
>   zone.js:677
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/
>   zone.js:686
>   drainMicroTaskQueue
>   zone.js:602
>   ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/
>   zone.js:500
>   invokeTask
>   zone.js:1540
>   globalZoneAwareCallback
>   zone.js:1566

My suspicion is some error in routing module so I'm pasting my config:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'wordspreview/:id',
    component: WordsPreviewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'wordspreview',
    component: WordsPreviewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:query',
    component: SearchResultsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/wordspreview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
};
```

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the bug for myself.

Unable to google it anywhere else, I will leave solution here to help next potential victims:

```
constructor(private router : Router,
[...]
this.router.navigate([site, id]);
```

What I did wrong was to navigate into wrong `site`. It was difficult to debug because it appeared only for some rare erroneous `site` values.